# I have some problems with mybatis, when I query presto data

Tags: java, mybatis, presto

When I query presto data with mybatis,

**It shows:**

> "com.facebook.presto.jdbc.NotImplementedException: Method Connection.prepareStatement is not yet implemented".

Anybody can help me?

Comment: It would be better to share some code or the command you've used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presto JDBC driver supports prepared statements for over a year now.
You need to upgrade the driver.
You can get the latest version from https://trino.io/download.html

Comment: I try it with your method, but it shows: “java.sql.SQLException: Authentication using username/password requires SSL to be enabled”.

What else do I need to do?

Comment: Presto JDBC always required SSL for user/password authentication, for security reasons.

Comment: If you need a hand in configuring your environment, I recommend that you join the Presto Community Slack https://prestosql.io/slack.html